# Can I call delayed_job with max attempts of 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have a method that I run asynchronously

```
User.delay(queue: 'users').grab_third_party_info(user.id)
```

In case this fails, I want it to not retry. My default retries are 3, which I cannot change. I just want to have this only try once. The following doesn't seem to work:

```
User.delay(queue: 'users', attempts: 3).grab_third_party_info(user.id)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get the Answer ?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't my favorite solution, but if you need to use the delay method that you can set the attempts: to one less your max attempts.  So in your case the following should work

```
User.delay(queue: 'users', attempts: 2).grab_third_party_info(user.id)
```

Better yet you could make it safer by using Delayed::Worker.max_attempts

```
User.delay(queue: 'users', attempts: Delayed::Worker.max_attempts-1).grab_third_party_info(user.id)
```

This would enter it into your delayed_jobs table as if it already ran twice so when it runs again it will be at the max attempts.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs

To set a per-job max attempts that overrides the Delayed::Worker.max_attempts you can define a max_attempts method on the job

```
NewsletterJob = Struct.new(:text, :emails) do
  def perform
    emails.each { |e| NewsletterMailer.deliver_text_to_email(text, e) }
  end

  def max_attempts
    3
  end
end
```

Does this help you?

Comment: No because you need to do that on a job that you create. I'm talking about just calling it with the delay method....

Answer (score 0):

#### You have to use a Custom Job.

Just like [@lazzi showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29994648/293280), you have to create a custom job in order to override the `max_attempts`.

As you can see in the README [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#parameters), the only params that the `.delay` method take are:

- `priority`
- `run_at`
- `queue`

And if you think about it, a value for `max_attempts` is not stored in the `delayed_jobs` table, only the `attempts` are stored, so there's no way for it to be persisted.

The only way to do it is to create a custom job that gets re-instantiated when the delayed job worker processes the job. It then reads the value from the `max_attempts` method and uses that to determine if the current `attempts` in the table record equals or exceeds the `max_attempts` value.

In your case, the simplest way to do it would be something like this:

```rb
# Inside your user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  FetchThirdPartyInfoJob = Struct.new( :user ) do 
  
    def perform
      User.grab_third_party_info(user.id) # REFACTOR: Make this an instance method so you don't need to pass the User's id to it.
    end

    def queue_name
      "users"
    end

    def max_attempts
      3
    end

  end

end
```

Then run it wherever you need to by using `enqueue`, like this:

```rb
Delayed::Job.enqueue( User::FetchThirdPartyInfoJob.new( user ) )
```

*I also added a little `REFACTOR` comment on your code because `User.grab_third_party_info(user.id)` looks to be incorrectly setup as a class method that you then pass the instance id to instead of just calling it directly on the `user` instance. I can't think of a reason why you would want this, but if there is, please leave it in the comments so we can all learn.*